# square fonts issue on wkhtmltopdf running on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64 bit compiled from source

Tags: linux, wkhtmltopdf

i compiled from source the wkhtmltopdf  using Qt 8.4 , every thing is working great but the output of the PDF fonts are square
i basically convert html pages from the web  for example :

```
./wkhtmltopdf --page-size A4 --disable-internal-links --disable-external-links
```

i think i scaned every help link that i found in google , but with out any result . 
what do i missing here ?
also did this script

```
#!/bin/sh
echo $*
export HOME="$PWD"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$PWD/lib/"
./wkhtmltopdf --page-size A4 --disable-internal-links --disable-external-links $1 $2  2>/$1
#exec $@ 2>/dev/null
#exec $@ 2>&1 # debug mode
```

Comment: Are you using special characters (e.g. Cyrillic or Japanese, or Latin letters with special accents, etc)? It could be that the default font is missing these special characters.